# ODE45 Singularity at the Initial Point

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

For the given differential equation,

[image]

with the initial condition **y(0) = 1**,

I am trying to find a solution using ODE45 method of MATLAB over the interval **[0 5]**. However, I noticed that the given equation is actually singular at the given initial point. Given the circumstances, how do you suggest I proceed?

What I have tried is that I can start the interval from **0 + δ** for some δ < 1e-5. However, this would be a crude approximation. The equation is not differentiable at the point 0.

Thank you so much,

Comment: As you saw, x=0 is an irregular singularity. Solutions with that initial value are not guaranteed to exist. The second term is can be considered a perturbation close to x=0, the remaining terms `y'(x)=x^(-3)` integrate as `y(x)-y(x0) = (x0^(-2)-x^(-2)/2`, which can not be extended to `x0=0`. Why do you believe a solution should exist?

Comment: Thank you LutzL. This is a homework question for one of my engineering classes.  
 I 've spent 10 hours on just this problem. While doing so, I read many articles on ill-posed differential problems, etc. Those articles were not much of an help. I couldn't quite convince myself that there should not be any solution. I should better get in contact with my professor and seek his help.

Comment: Take a look at [Maple's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM79e.png) of this problem (`_zl` is just a temporary integration variable, you can replace it with `z` for readability). As you can see, the integral is undefined at the lower bound, which means that it only ever works for `x=0`, where it equals 0. As a fellow engineer, I would suggest using a symbolic solver for simple problems like that (to see if there's even a point in trying to implement it in MATLAB).